# Why is UIComponent.setStyleClass() not working in JSF 2.1 converters?

Tags: java, jsf-2

If I call `setStyleClass` on the `UIComponent` reference in JSF converters `getAsString(...)` method the stated class is not applied.

If I do the same in a backing bean on a bound component (with "binding") it works as expected.

The converter is called, it's registered properly.

Here's my converter:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = MoneyAmount.class)
public class MoneyAmountConverter implements Converter {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return null;        
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        MoneyAmount amount = (MoneyAmount) value;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(amount.getCurrency());
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(amount.getAmount());

        if( component instanceof HtmlOutputLabel ) {
            HtmlOutputLabel lbl = (HtmlOutputLabel) component;
            log.info("isOutputLabel for: {}", sb.toString());
            if( amount.isNegative() ) {
                log.info("setting style to red");
                lbl.setStyleClass("red");
            } else {
                log.info("setting style to blue");
                lbl.setStyleClass("blue");
            }            
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }   
}
```

Thank you in anticipation!

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug this code? From looking at the code, I guess the problem is that you will probably not have the converter on a `HtmlOutputLabel` component.

Is this `h:outputLabel` linked to a `h:inputText` via the `for`attribute? In this case the `instanceof` will probably always return `false` as the component converted will be `HtmlInputText`.

Comment: Yes, I debugged it and setStyleClass is  invoked. The log includes the messages from the code.